# Why did my calculator take this number for $e^x=0$, or better why does he even give a solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

My calculator gives a solution to $e^x=0$, this on itself quite strange, but the value is also interesting: $x=-9,9997457056636 \times 10^{98}$. My best guess is that it has to do with the limit of $x$ approaches minus infinity, but then why not choose $1 \times 10^{99}$ and not a very specific number?

What perhaps also helps is a picture of the result and the make of the calculator, it is a TI-84 Plus CE-T[image]

Comment: I imagine it is solving numerically, and at that value of $x$ the error goes beyond machine precision and the result is 0.  Your calculator is not sophisticated enough to understand that there is no solution.

Comment: your calculator just did a numerical approximation, so had an accuracy range which it imposed, and that accuracy happened to be achieved with your very large negative number result.

Comment: To give a real answer as to why it gives that result for $x$ we'd have to know much more about the specifics of the software.  But most likely it has to do with the solver algorithm, and the way it stores and processes floating point numbers, and not much to do with the math per-se.

Comment: @JairTaylor The actual solution is not 0 because $e^0=1 \neq 0.$

Comment: Calculator is (likely) using Newton's method. Because there is no solution ($\lim_{y \to 0} \log y = -\infty$), it keeps finding smaller and smaller numbers with Newton's method. Likely this was the last step before it hit its own computational limit (of, presumably, $9.99999 \cdots \times 10^{99}$. It simply output the last usable number it found.

Comment: @coffeemath I didn't say the solution was at $x=0$. I meant that the result, $e^x$, was given as $0$ due to floating point error.

Comment: @JairTaylor $x=−9,9997457056636×10^{98}$ is in fact a (bad) calculator approximation to $- \infty.$
 .

Comment: What are you guys talking about...$e^x=0$ has a solution and it is $x=-\infty$

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I for one was agreeing with the $x=-\infty$ result, and just pointing out the calculator gave a numeric which is in some sense as good as it could if it has no symbol for negative infinity but must use  float.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes... that's my point. I don't think we disagree about anything?

Comment: Note that the TI-82/83/84(+) calculators don't have a representation for infinity.  [You're expected to use ±1E99 instead.](https://education.ti.com/en/customer-support/knowledge-base/ti-83-84-plus-family/product-usage/34840)

Comment: @Dan yer right. deleting...

Comment: @EricSnyder: I doubt that it's Newton's Method, because with $f(x) = f'(x) = e^x$, you'd just be subtracting 1 on each iteration.  So if your starting guess were any reasonable small integer, you'd end up with $x = -228$ (at which point $e^x < 10^{-99}$ and thus underflows to zero on the TI-84+).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it should be noted that [the TI-84 Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-84_Plus_series) does **not** have a built-in [computer algebra system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) like the [TI-89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-89_series) or [TI-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-92_series).  It can only give numerical answers.

Also note that, [according to the manual](https://www.manua.ls/texas-instruments/ti-84-plus/manual?p=405), “Values are stored in memory using up to 14 digits with a two-digit exponent.”  Thus, the greatest (absolute value) number that can be represented on this calculator is $9.9999999999999 \times 10^{99}$. Conversely, the smallest positive number that's distinguishable from zero is $1.0 \times 10^{-99}$.  Numbers are stored in a [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)-based format so that exact decimal fractions can be represented exactly.  Contrast with the [double-precision binary floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) popular on personal computers, which have a wider range (up to $1.7976931348623157 \times 10^{308}$), but cannot exactly represent $0.1$ or $0.01$.

So, according to the rules of TI-84+ arithmetic, any $x < \ln(10^{-99}) \approx -227.95592420641$ is a valid solution to the equation $e^x = 0$, since the calculation of $e^x$ will [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

Still, there are a *lot* of representable numbers between $-9.9999999999999 \times 10^{99}$ and $-227.95592420642$, so why pick $−9.9997457056636 \times 10^{98}$ in particular, rather than a nice round $-10^{99}$?  Well, that's hard to answer without seeing the exact code for the root-finding algorithm.  (I tried to speculate, but couldn't get the math to work out.)

Point is, numerical solvers behave weirdly when a function has an asymptote, so be skeptical when your calculator shows you an unusually large or small number.